# How can I concatenate the values in one excel column that match a date in another column?

Tags: excel, date, text, concatenation, multiple-columns

I have an Excel table that includes a date column and a notes(text) column.
In a separate column on another sheet, I want to concatenate the notes cells that correspond with a date.
I need it to look like this:
[image: desired result]

The table with the "Notes" column I need to concatenate looks like this:
[image: example]
Have tried multiple variations on if, ifs and concat. Can't get anything to work.
Any suggestions. No VBA preferred.

Comment: What is your excel version?

Answer (score 0):

With Microsoft 365 can use-

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$2:$A2,A2)=1,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER([Notes],[Date]=[@Date])),"")
```

[image]

Comment: the thing is, the desired column is in another table on a different sheet next to a pivot table that combines all dates into one row. I need the "Notes" column next to the pivot table to show all the notes in the data table with that date.

Comment: No issue, use same formula and just change function arguments.